# How can I position my carousel at the bottom of my page?

Tags: html, css, carousel

I saw this pure css carousel design in this [link here](https://codepen.io/ancaspatariu/pen/WpQYOP). Now, I want this to be on the bottom of my page.

**Code snippet:**

```css
.carousel {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}

ul.slides {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

ul.slides input {
    display: none; 
}


.slide-container { 
    display: block; 
}

.slide-image {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}   

.slide-image img {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-controls {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 600px;
    color: #fff;
}

.carousel-controls label {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slide-image:hover + .carousel-controls label{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.carousel-controls label:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-controls .prev-slide {
    width: 49%;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0;
}

.carousel-controls .next-slide {
    width: 49%;
    text-align: right;
    right: 0;
}

.carousel-dots {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-dots .carousel-dot {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin: 10px;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .slide-image {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .carousel-controls label {
     display: block; 
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-6 {
 opacity: 1;
}


input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="carousel">
        <ul class="slides">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-1" checked />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide-image">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Timisoara_-_Regional_Business_Centre.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-controls">
                    <label for="img-3" class="prev-slide">
                        <span>&lsaquo;</span>
                    </label>
                    <label for="img-2" class="next-slide">
                      <span>&rsaquo;</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-2" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide-image">
                    <img src="http://www.timisoaranight.gruzphoto.eu/IMG_8554.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-controls">
                    <label for="img-1" class="prev-slide">
                        <span>&lsaquo;</span>
                    </label>
                    <label for="img-3" class="next-slide">
                        <span>&rsaquo;</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-3" />
            <li class="slide-container">
                <div class="slide-image">
                    <img src="https://speakzeasy.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/twa_blogpic_timisoara-4415.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-controls">
                    <label for="img-2" class="prev-slide">
                        <span>&lsaquo;</span>
                    </label>
                    <label for="img-1" class="next-slide">
                        <span>&rsaquo;</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <div class="carousel-dots">
                <label for="img-1" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
                <label for="img-2" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
                <label for="img-3" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried adding `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` to the `.carousel` div but the carousel will go nowhere. I also tried adding `position: relative` to the most outer div but to no avail.

I didnt change anything from this [link](https://codepen.io/ancaspatariu/pen/WpQYOP), except the `position` attributes.

I really want this carousel just to be in the bottom of page. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `position: fixed` or `position: sticky` yet?

Comment: @stealththeninja to the outer `div` that holds the `.carousel`? I just tried, but no

Comment: it would be better if you update your code too.

Comment: While staying with position:relative... what happens when you add this carousel to the bottom of your page? in the example, if you try adding other stuff (headings, paragraph etc) before this div, the carousel will be at the bottom

Comment: @Sushil what do you mean? I changed nothing from the original code

Comment: update your code or provide a demo on online compilers

Comment: @Sushil someone added the snippet and here is the [link](https://codepen.io/ancaspatariu/pen/WpQYOP) if you want

Comment: @AkberIqbal here's an [image](https://ibb.co/6P7pgN6)

Comment: @CodeRed check the answer below. I have done it with https://codepen.io/ancaspatariu/pen/WpQYOP this link. Hope you get your answer.

Comment: @Sushil it worked, i just dont know why you set width to 50. but its ok now

Comment: @CodeRed I have added this for testing you can modify as per your requirements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185900/discussion-between-codered-and-sushil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `CSS`. Hope this works fine.

You can Change `margin-left`, `margin-right` and `width` as per your requirement.

```
.carousel {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    bottom:0;
   position:fixed;
   width:50%;
 }
```

Comment: thank you sir. It worked, i just made few changes to your code

Comment: @CodeRed, It was great getting to know you